# Mysterious NullPointerException gets thrown when working with a Spinner

Tags: android

I have a clickable TextView and a Spinner whose visibility is set to `GONE`.

This is my layout snippet:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/strip1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="  Order Name       ID      Description     Type" 
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Spinner android:id="@+id/sortSpinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:prompt="@string/prompt" />
```

In `onCreate` I have this:

```
TextView strip = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.strip1);
strip.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        spinner_show();
    }

});
```

`spinner_show()` looks like this:

```
private void spinner_show() {

    String str = new String[2];
    str[0] = "Ascending";
    str[1] = "Descending";

    Spinner sortSpin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sortSpinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> sizeArrayAdapter =
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, str);
    sizeArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sortSpin.setAdapter(sizeArrayAdapter);
    sortSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(
        new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                    View v, int pos, long id) {

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        } 
    });
```

The application is throwing a `NullPointerException` and I can't figure out why.

Here is the logcat snippet:

```
12-14 14:57:31.388: W/dalvikvm(3794): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught    exception (group=0x40015560)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownView(ArrayAdapter.java:376)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(Spinner.java:332)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(Spinner.java:328)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1409)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at com.android.internal.widget.WeightedLinearLayout.onMeasure(WeightedLinearLayout.java:60)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-14 14:57:31.468: E/AndroidRuntime(3794):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please post error log...

Comment: run "adb logcat AndroidRuntime:* *:S" in the command line then run the app. This will show just the exception information, then post it here. One thing I do when I get crashes that I think should never happen is to start commenting code out until the crash goes away. At least then you have and Idea where to look. From your post we don't know if it's crashing in onCreate or in your spinner_show function.

Comment: Inspect your stack trace and take a look at the line number which throws the exception.

Comment: I tested your code it works fine just you need to change the String str=new String[2]; to String[] str=new String[2];

Comment: Try : clean and build your project and then run it..

Comment: Just post whole activity code, also with your xml file name..

Comment: @user370305 Reread the title. It says a mysterious NullPointerException. Not a mysterious question.

Comment: @OctavianDamiean:it became casual but i have to post on your comment.Good sense of humor.I get laugh when i read your comment.Please no body take it in wrong way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, First of all, your xml layout file,

```
          <TextView
    android:id="@+id/strip1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="  Order Name       ID      Description     Type" 
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

<Spinner android:id="@+id/sortSpinner"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
         android:visibility="gone"
         android:clickable="true"
         android:prompt="@string/prompt"/>
```

In your xml file your TextView has `android:layout_weight="1"` so its cover all layout, No space for Spinner (This also doesn't cause NullPointerException So its not necessary),

Now from your java class file,

```
 private void spinner_show()  
    {

        String[] str=new String[2]; // problem on declaring String array
        str[0]="Ascending";
        str[1]="Descending";

        Spinner sortSpin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sortSpinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> sizeArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>    (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,str);
        sizeArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sortSpin.setAdapter(sizeArrayAdapter);
        sortSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {

            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            } 
        });

        sortSpin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // also you don't Visiable your spinner
   }
```

**And the main things is its works fine in my eclipse**, I have just removed    `android:prompt="@string/prompt"` attribute from xml file because I don't have a String Prompt..

Comment: Also I am definitely sure, the code posted in question is not contain any line which get null pointer exception so I think, He has to be post whole activity code, And the silly mistake in code is just String array declaration but it not cause NullPointerException..

Comment: Indeed. What he posted should work. I just wanted to let you know that there as absolutely no problem with his `layout_weight`. If he hasn't set anything special for the parent's `weightSum`, then the Spinner will just appear at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @Octavian Damiean - Yes, He posted the code is works fine also layout_weight doesn't cause the any problem, I just mentioned it for check the code.. The posted code works fine..

Answer (score 0):

Because you have made spinner visibility as gone then how can it is able to show your spinner.

so call `sortSpin.SetVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: Do you really think that _this_ causes a `NullPointerException`? I don't think so.